# positive/negative fields of function that includes integrals

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

**Edit: please follow the comments on the suggested answer, I still do need help.**

Given (), a continuous and positive function for every x.
We define a new function () in the following way:
[image]

I have found the Derivative for g(x) and want to know when it's positive/negative/equal to zero

Here's my findings till now I found g'x: (sorry for adding a picture, I don't know how to write them here)

[image]

also I found that when x=0 g'(x) is equal to 1.

But how can I continue from here, I am a little bit confused with x and t since they have the same job...

proof that g'(0)=1:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$ \forall x\neq0,g'(x)=f(x)\left(\int_0^x f(t)dt\right)^{-2}\left(x\int_0^x f(t)dt-\int_0^x tf(t)dt\right) $$
Since $f\geqslant 0$, $\forall t\in[0,x],tf(t)\leqslant xf(t)$ so that $g'(x)\geqslant 0$ for $x>0$. If $x<0$, we still have $tf(t)\leqslant xf(t)$ for $t\in[0,x]$ but $g'(x)\leqslant 0$ because $x<0$.

Comment: Please Note; f>0 (it can't be equal to 0)

Comment: $f>0$ does not mean that $f\geqslant 0$ and $f\neq 0$, it means that $\forall x, f(x)>0$, which is not the same thing.

Comment: according to your answer x=0 is where g'(x)=0 but that's not right

Comment: $x=t$ ? But $t$ is not defined, it is a free variable, it makes no sense... I proved that $g'(x)\geqslant 0$ for $x>0$ and $g'(x)\leqslant 0$ for $x<0$. And $g'(x)=0\iff f(x)=0$ or $x\int_0^x f(t)dt=\int_0^x tf(t)dt$. Moreover, if $x\int_0^x f(t)dt=\int_0^x tf(t)dt$, $\int_0^x(xf(t)-tf(t))dt=0$. If there exists $x\neq 0$ such that $\int_0^x(xf(t)-tf(t))dt=0$, since $t\mapsto xf(t)-tf(t)$ is positive and continuous, then $xf(t)-tf(t)=0$ for all $t\in[0,x]$. If we suppose that $f(t)>0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, then $t=x$ for all $t\in[0,x]$ which is not. Thus $g'(x)=0\iff x=0$ because $f(x)>0$.

Comment: ok you said g'(x) = 0 if x=0 but since we know that x is different than 0 (in the first case of g'(x)) this says that g'(x) is never equal to 0! but we know that g(x) is going up when x>=0 and going down when x<=0 that says (given f is continues) x=0 should be the point where g'(x)=0. it's a contradiction

Comment: How did you find $g'(0)=1$ ?

Comment: see the last image in my edited post